# Maximum number of rounds needed for a multiple strike tournament

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have a spreadsheet set up that will allow me to track video game tournaments (although it can be used for other types of tournaments as well). The formulas that I created the spreadsheet with provide an approximate number of rounds needed for the tournament based on the total number of players, the number of players allowed per game, the number of strikes per game, and the number of strikes a player may receive before being eliminated from the tournament.

My formula works pretty well for single-strike tournaments, but I've found that my estimates get less accurate as I increase the number of strikes a player may receive.

I am currently in the process of rebuilding my spreadsheet and would like to change my formula from estimating the number of rounds to providing the maximum number of rounds required based on the following:

- Total Player Count (*P*)
- Players per game (*n*)
- Strikes per Game (*x*)
- Strikes allowed (*S*)

By way of information, here are the ranges that I am looking at for each variable:

- *P*: 4 through 150(ish)
- *n*: 2 through 8
- *x*: 1 through *n*-1
- *S*: 1 through 3

Also, I'm not a mathematician. But I'm pretty okay with formulas (particularly in Excel). My apologies if any of my formatting and/or nomenclature are in error.

Comment: Some more information might be useful.  For instance, in a 4 player game, can one player receive 3 strikes and the other three receive 0 strikes?  If so, can a player who has one less than the maximum number of strikes at the start of a game receive multiple strikes in that game?

Comment: Also, is a "round" the same as a "game"? And is "strikes per game" the total number of strikes in a game or maximum number of strikes per game per player? And are strikes assumed to be random? I.e is there an equal probability that any player (other than the striker) is hit by a strike?